# Excel - Find & Replace Char

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My column has data in the format of "text-text-number" e.g. "D1-flac-1" but the latter number sorts incorrectly, which was because it lacked a "0" in it for it to list by 0,1,2 instead of 0,1,11,2...

Is there a way I can use the find/replace functionality to fix ONLY the latter portion of the cell? Ideally I need to know a wildcard to find e.g. only 1 character after the hyphen then add a zero to it.

[image]

Ive seen you can fix this with a new sorting column but I cannot add a column to what Im doing, I need to fix the original column.

[image]

Comment: wildcards only work with text, not numbers. If you do not want to use formulas(helper column) then VBA is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can loop though the cells and then split the value on "-" and then format last part as "00". Finally join them and put them back

Comment: Its upwards of 1,000 rows, the above is just a smaller example of the format. that's why i needed a function or find/replace to do them all :)

Comment: It took me just 2 minutes to write the code and couple of seconds to runs it. Like I said you cannot use (I could be wrong) Find and Replace with wildcards to search for numbers like this

Comment: Sorry, I just am not familiar with using VBA, its really not that I'm lazy or anything like that. But thank you, I will google more on VBA

Comment: Sure. give it a try and if you get stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there :)

Comment: This is the main part of my testing function but its changing things literally to be star, so I imagine its not using the wildcard i had hoped it would.


fnd = "-(star)"
rplc = "-0(star)" 
Range("A1:A99999").Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc,

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to sort on the numerical position then you can also try below option.

1. In spare column, write following formula.

   `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99))+0`

   Copy down till last row of your data.
2. Sort your data in ascending order based on the spare formula column thus created.
3. Delete the spare column afterwards if you don't need it further.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a minute to wrap my head around what you meant but I think I've got it working

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the numeric portion into another column for sorting, assuming you always have the same format in your first column, you can:

- Select your column of data
- Data `Text to columns`

  - Step 2: Delimiters/Other: `-`
  - Step 3:

    - Select Columns 1 and 2 and **do not import**
    - Destination:  **B1**

[image]

Then, when you finish, the unsplit original will be in column A, and the numeric portion in column B as numbers.

- Select columns A & B
- sort ascending on Column B.
- Delete column B

*You can put the numeric column in any location if column B is not available*

**before sorting**

[image]

**after sorting**

[image]